# Adding a input field, looping though it and outputting values to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a little rusty so this may be a simple fix. I am trying to get code that adds a input field dynamically through an add more button. Then using jquery, the code then loops through gets the values of the input fields and appends a div. This is what I have so far.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.addurl').click(function() {
    $('.more').add('<input name="more" type="text" class="test">').appendTo('.more');
  });
  
  $('.more').on('change', function() {
    $('.test').each(function() {
      var test = $(this).val();
      alert(test);
      $("<div id='urlnm2'> URL:" + test + "</div>").appendTo($('#urlnm'));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="url" name="url" type="text">
<div class="more"></div>
<button type="button" class="addurl">Add more</button>
```

The problem is when I click to add the first input field, my output is

URL1

URL2

Which is what I want but if I add a 3rd input field, my output is

URL1

URL2

URL2

URL3

which isn't what I want. I need it to be

URL1

URL2

URL3

Please help. I've been stuck on this for a day. Thanks

Comment: please post HTML OF  id`urlnm` too

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have added that to the code snippet, and I can only assume that's what OP intended.

Comment: @Terry  i think you have to revert back both changes and let OP have to put his own HTML AND SCRIPT code. there. It's really bad to change and add your code into OP's question, because it change the whole structure/meaning of the question. Please revert it back to original

Comment: I did not change anything except for porting it over to a code snippet and adding the div with the ID of `urlnm`. If you think that is bad, I believe you have the rep to rollback: not going to contest that.

Comment: Being the OP. Actually, the answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much @Satpal

Comment: hi @user1937895.. FYI..  I have added an "improved" version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clear the content of the div using `.empty()` then use `.append()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.addurl').click(function() {
    $('.more').add('<input name="more" type="text" class="test">').appendTo('.more');
  });

  $('.more').on('change', '.test', function() {
    var container = $('#urlnm').empty();
    $('.test').each(function() {
      //if you want to use id, create a mechanism so that identifiers must be unique
      $("<span> URL:" + $(this).val() + "</div>").appendTo(container);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="url" name="url" type="text" class="test">
<div class="more"></div>
<button type="button" class="addurl">Add more</button>
 <!-- Create this div -->
<div id="urlnm"></div>
```

Also note: Identifiers in HTML must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Added a "cleaner" version, IMHO.

- Display result after first input
- You can actually removed the `more` class box
- Remove div `change` event handling

Bonus:

- Synchronize changes on all input textboxes

```js
$(function() {

  $('.addurl').click(function(e) {

    // clear result box
    $('#result').empty();

    // read all input textbox and show result
    $("#box-input .test").each(function() {
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      addOutputBox(inputValue);
    });

    // add input textbox
    $('<input type="text" class="test"><br/>').appendTo('#box-input');

  });

  function addOutputBox(urlValue) {
    $("<div class='output'>URL: " + urlValue + "</div>").appendTo('#result');
  }

  // handle input even on all textboxes
  $("#box-input").on("input", ".test", function(e) {
  
    // console.log("changes", currentIndex, $(this).val() );
    
    var totalOutput = $("#result .output").length;
    var totalInput = $("#box-input .test").length;
    
    if ( totalOutput === 0 || totalOutput < totalInput) {
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      addOutputBox(inputValue);
      return;
    }
    
    // Get current index of the input textbox
    var currentIndex = $("#box-input .test").index( this );
    
    // Output[currentIndex] = Input[currentIndex] 
    $("#result .output").eq(currentIndex).html("URL: " + $(this).val() );
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box-input">
  <input id="url" name="url" class="test" type="text"><br/>
</div>

<button type="button" class="addurl">Add more</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```